# __class_ data member in python, how it is different from static data member in java

Tags: python

i am trying to execute following code to understand Class data member in python, but it is throwing StopIteration error,

```
class PizzaShop():
    pizza_stock = 10
    def get_pizza(self):
        while not PizzaShop.pizza_stock:
            PizzaShop.pizza_stock -= 1
            yield "take yours pizza order, total pizzas left {}".format(PizzaShop.pizza_stock)

mypizza_shop = PizzaShop()
pizza_order = mypizza_shop.get_pizza() 
print "{}".format(repr(pizza_order.next()))
```

i am expecting that it should first print some message and then any exception
i am using python 2.7, ubuntu 32bits os

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/scott/pythonfiles/core_python/pizza.py", line 10, in <module>
print "{}".format(repr(pizza_order.next()))
StopIteration
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
while not PizzaShop.pizza_stock:
```

This will stop immediately if pizza_stock is nonzero. Which it always is. You probably intended to write

```
while PizzaShop.pizza_stock:
```

Anyway, if you want to find the details on how values, classes, etc. behave in Python, you should check [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html). It's very different from Java.

P.S. The following is unnecessary as `str.format` has a shorthand for calling repr. Also, you shouldn't call magic methods like `.next` directly. Use the builtin `next()` instead.

```
print "{}".format(repr(pizza_order.next()))
```

Should be

```
print "{!r}".format(next(pizza_order))
```